# Class constructor refer to self to add to vector

Tags: c++

I appear to be unable to make the constructor add the class instance to a vector. Here's the code I got:

main.cpp

```
#include "object.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

vector <object> objects;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     object foo(1);
     objects.push_back(foo);
     return 0;
}
```

object.h

```
class object {
public:
    int foo;
    object(int);
};
```

object.cpp

```
#include "object.h"
object (int foo) {
    object::foo = foo;
}
```

I want to move that objects.push_back(foo) into the .cpp file.
I've tried using extern and it works except for one thing: how do I reference the object being constructed from within the constructor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the **actual** code. The code you’ve posted is invalid and won’t compile.

Comment: In particular `object foo();` does not create an `object` called `foo`. Instead, it declares a function called `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, never mind. Found the issue.
Managed to use the keyword "this".
My issue was that it was a pointer and my vector stored objects.
So I just placed:

```
objects.push_back(*this);
```

and it worked!
Thanks anyway, may this be of use to someone else in the future.

Comment: Remember that this will make a copy.

Comment: Yes, I removed the push_back in the main function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this

```
object foo();
```

is a function declaration that does not have parameters an returns an object of type int.

Secondly your class object has no the default constructor. It has a constructor with parameter.

```
object(int);
```

So when you create an object of type object you shall specify an argument.

Take into account that this definition of the class is syntaxical invalid

```
class object {
public:
    int foo;
    object(int)
}
```

You forgot to place two semicolons: one after rge constructor declaration and other after the closing brace of the class definition. Should be

```
class object {
public:
    int foo;
    object(int);
};
```

Also the constructor shall be defined as

```
object::object (int foo) {
    object::foo = foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the following code, which is part of your main:

```
class object {};

int main() {
    object foo();
}
```

This code, when compiled under clang, reports the following:

```
foo.cc:4:15: warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    object foo();
              ^~
foo.cc:4:15: note: remove parentheses to declare a variable
    object foo();
              ^~
1 warning generated.
```

This is known in C++ as the [**Most Vexing Parse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You can resolve this by instead writing:

```
int main() {
    object foo;
}
```

Comment: I think that the most vexing parse is when you have something like `A foo(B());`, whereas this is just a not-so-vexing parse.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: They both are, but this variant is very easy to resolve because you can just drop the parentheses all together.

Comment: Which is why it's not quite as vexing. :)